# Is there any way to count the number of mentions made by a particular twitter id without authentication

Tags: php, twitter

Is there any way in php to find out the total number of mentions made by a particular twitter id.Suppose my Twitter Id is 123456789 or my screen name is "ABCD" . I want to calculate total number of mentions made by me(i.e. @andrew) so far.I want to do this without user authentication.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to find out how often a certain user was mentioned by others or how often a certain user mentions others?

Comment: @walterlos Im looking for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Very well, both cases. In the case of finding out how often a certain user mentions others you could use the user_timeline resource without needing authentication. You could fetch 200 tweets by a user a time and then make use of the since_id parameter to keep fetching older tweets. For every tweet you can then check if it contains a mentions.

As for the other case, I'm not sure. You could use the search API with a search string of "to:username" for @replies or a search string of "username" which would yield tweets by that user, as well as @replies and @mentions. Twitter search only gives results for the last couple of days though so I doubt that this would help you.

Good luck!